# openlayers get latest feature added on vectorlayer

Tags: vector, openlayers, layer

I try to get the latest featureID (e.g. 'OpenLayers_Feature_Vector_86') directly after adding the feature to the vectorlayer.

I tried to add an eventlistener:

```
eventListeners: {
 "featuresadded": function(feature) {
   alert(feature.fid);
  }
}
```

The feature is added with the following code:

```
vectors.addFeatures(geojson_format.read(featurecollection));
```

Thanks in advance
Florian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`featuresadded` (note the plural form) passes a whole *array* of features added (even if it's a single feature it's still wrapped in an array), in your example you're trying to access a `fid` property of an array of features, which returns `undefined`. You should either:

1. Listen for the `featureadded` event (singular form):

> The event object passed to listeners will have a feature property with a reference to the added feature.
>
> Extract the relevant feature inside the `featuresadded` handler, i.e.:

```
featuresadded: function(features) {
  var lastFeature = features[features.length - 1];
  var lastFeatureId = lastFeature.id;
}
```

---

As a general tip: I'd recommend using `console.log` instead of `alert` for debugging, it shows all the properties of an object, enabling you to inspect it (in this case: see that the ID property is called `id`, not `fid`). Alert coerces the object to a string, often showing something unhelpful like `[object Object]`